# simplesamlphp with composer overwrites the configuration files when updating

Tags: composer-php, simplesamlphp

I have installed SimpleSAMLphp in my project using Composer, configured it and have it working nicely.

Unfortunately, every time I do a composer update the config.php, authsources.php and saml20-idp-remote.php files are deleted.

The documentation suggests a way of providing an alternative location or the config.php file but not for the other two.

Can anyone suggest a setting up SimpleSAMLphp with these files located outside of the vendor\SimpleSAMLphp folder?

I'm currently using a script to copy locally stored copies of these files back to the correct folder on a post-update trigger, but it seems to me to be a bit of a kludge.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`SIMPLESAMLPHP_CONFIG_DIR`](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/1.14/simplesamlphp-install#section_6) lets you specify the `config` directory with an env variable. SSP will look in that folder for `config.php` and  `authsources.php`. You can define where the metadata files are stored with a variable inside `config.php`

```
'metadata.sources' => array(
     array('type' => 'flatfile', 'directory' =>  '/your/path/metadata'),
),
```

The above example will tell SSP to look in `/your/path/metadata` for `saml20-idp-remote.php` (and other metadata files)

There can be some other challenges using SSP installed this way - in particular if you need to install additional modules SSP expects them to be in (or symlinked from) it's modules directory.

Comment: Many thanks for the quick reply, I'll have a try at this later in the week when I get back to the SSO project. Fortunately we're only using a bog-standard SImpleSAMLphp setup for the SP.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in marking this as correct, I had to reengineer my applications to use a single Service Provider to make it work. But work it does, so many thanks.

Comment: Ran into this issue today. I also have a custom module so that makes things complicated. I don't have access to the virtual host settings on production either. I guess I'll write a githook :(